# Use variable subdomains for routing with wildcard

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I want to create an express application that uses dynamic/variable subdomains for routing. This is what I want to do:

- `http://<username>.mysite.dev` should forward the requests to the `users/index.js`

In the `users/index.js` I will access the username via `req.subdomain[0]`. It would be nice if I could also run an regular expression check on `<username>`.

**My first approach:**

I am using the node package `express-subdomain` to route the requests:

```
/* import node packages */
var express     = require('express'),
    subdomain   = require('express-subdomain');

/* application config */
var app   = express(),
    port  = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/* import all apps */
var users = require('./users/index.js');

/* route requests by subdomain */
app.use(subdomain('*', users));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  /* Never get here */
  res.send('Homepage'); 
});

/* run app on given port */
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port + ' ...');
});
```

The problem with this approach is that the `*` is not working properly. It forwards **all** requests to my `users/index.js` even when there is no subdomain (`http://mysite.dev`). One solution for this problem would be, if I change the routing like this:

```
app.use(subdomain('*.users', users));
```

So I can access the `users/index.js` through `http://<user>.users.mysite.dev` and I can also reach the normal site, when there is no subdomain. But this approach is not really what I want - the `users` subdomain is too much. In addition I can not use regex.

Now, I am searching for a better solution for this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/patmood/wildcard-subdomains provides same functionality